# Eclipse Kura installation on raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, kura

I want to install Eclipse kura on Raspberry pi 3(Rasbarian or Ubuntu mate OS)

According to [kura download page](https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php), I have tried out both network and no-network samples(kura_2.1.0_raspberry-pi-2-3_installer.deb and ) and (kura_2.1.0_raspberry-pi-2-3-nn_installer.deb)separately.

According to http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/raspberry-pi-quick-start.html, it asked to purge dhcpcd5 and remove network manager first and then need to install the kura. 
Issue is,

According to https://iot.eclipse.org/java/tutorial page, it installs kura without removing/purging dhcpcd5/network manager settings.

Let me the know the correct method to install eclipse kura on raspberry pi 3. 
(supposed eclise kura 1.4 or 2.1 with Rasbarian or Ubuntu mate os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Raspbian and following the instructions here: http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/raspberry-pi-quick-start.html. That documentation is kept the most current.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Thank you. I hope, it is better to update the document with new version(2.1). I initially tried with Ubuntu mate and not getting success. It seems that it work only with Rasbarian OS.

Comment: 1. Is that possible to install kura on Ubuntu or Centos VM ? 
2. In the downloads, we can see sample downloads for few development boards only, we cannot see the sample to install on linux VM. What are the steps if we going to install kura on linux machine ?

Comment: Kura is not a 100% "pure Java" application. There are dependencies on both native libraries and OS versions. Kura is likely to work with the Ubuntu OS, but I would try the "nn" or "no networking" versions of the installer. You may also have to compile the udev native code (https://github.com/eclipse/kura/tree/develop/kura/org.eclipse.kura.linux.usb/src/main/c/udev), depending on your target architecture.

Comment: Thank you. Let us know your results. It is difficult to compile the udev code with target architecture, since it require lot of linux, C knowledge. If better we can have installer that match to specific ubuntu version like raspberry pi, so that we can directly install it.

Comment: according to kura downloads, https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php kura can install only on Raspbian, Intel Edison, BeagleBone devices right ? Other than what are the possible devices we can install kura ? Let us know the complete guidance to install kura on specific ubuntu or centos or fedora machine(Computer with linux os) ?