# Eclipse Kura installation on Linux machines or VM

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, iot, kura

We know that eclipse kura can be installed on edge devices and Raspberry pi is the most popular edge device at now.

As per https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php, we can see various downloads for Raspberry pi, Intel Edition, BeagleBone and Fedora with the beta release.

But we couldn't see the download link to install it on Linux machines or VM. (Ubuntu or centos VM ). We want to install it on ubuntu machine and possible to view web UI on that machine.

**EDIT**(edit the question)

1. Is that possible to install only on Fedora ?
2. What are the complete steps to install kura on ubuntu or Centos ?

Comment: This isn't the place to ask about Eclipse release plans.

Comment: @greg-449, I have edit the question based on ur comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826034/eclipse-kura-installation-on-raspberry-pi-3). To summarize, there is no generic installer for Ubuntu, Fedora, or CentOS. Kura has dependencies on both the OS and CPU architecture. The supported platforms are:

- Raspberry Pi based on Raspbian: Raspberry Pi, Raspberry Pi B+,
  Raspberry Pi 2/3
- BeagleBone Black based on Debian
- Fedora 25 ARM
- Intel Edison

The "No Net" versions of the posted installers will remove most of the OS dependencies. For CPU architectures, if you are using something other than ARMv6 HF or x86_64, you will need to compile the native libraries. The minimum native library needed for Kura to start is [udev](https://github.com/eclipse/kura/tree/develop/kura/org.eclipse.kura.linux.usb/src/main/c/udev).

Comment: As per you "No Net" version of the above installers will work on x86_64 architecture as well.    Let's say we have Intel Core i-5 computer with ubuntu or centos, the architecture is x86_64. What is the installer, that we need to install ? Is it BeagleBone black based on Debian ??

Comment: The only installer that uses the x86_64 native libs is the Intel Edison installer.